# Swift Cannot Invoke Add Target for UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am trying to translate my objective C code to Swift and I have this working in Objective C. I would like to run a method called "doneEnteringText" when the user hits return on the keyboard that appears from tapping on a certain text field. Here is the objective C code which works perfectly:

```
    [_nameTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(doneEnteringText) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

Here is my swift translation:

```
nameTextField.addTarget(self, action: doneEnteringText(), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)
```

When I try to compile the Swift code, I get an error saying that I "cannot invoke addTarget with an argument of list type....
Any idea why? Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Try using "doneEnteringText" string instead of doneEnteringText()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `doneEnteringText()` is a method call, not a selector. Thus, it cannot be an equivalent of Objective-C `@selector(doneEnteringText)`. In Swift, you want to say it as a string, `"doneEnteringText"`.

Comment: I tried that but now i get a similar error but instead of listing action: (), it lists action: () -> ()

Comment: What I said is right. Look at the link I gave you, which shows a working example! I have no way of knowing what you're doing wrong now in your new code, but I answered correctly the question you answered, as far as it went.

Comment: Oh ok now it works, I did not realize that you meant that you need to put doneEnteringText as a literal string, I was ignoring the quotation marks you put in your answer. Stupid mistake by me!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.2 selector syntax changed. You should use it like

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.doneEnteringText), forControlEvents: .UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)
```

Answer (score 0):

yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: "YourFunction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)